# Как отображать большие координаты в карте (Leaflet)?

Tags: leafletjs, geojson

Как отображать большие координаты в системе координат в карте (leaflet)?
POINT(7945127.97143797 5297067.84665206)

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваши координаты корректны? Допустимый диапазон широты в градусах от -90 до +90, долготы от -180 до +180

Comment: да, уверен, проверял через openlayer там корректно отображается

Comment: а как вы проверяли?

Comment: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-formats.html вот здесь
POINT(7946684.68075273 5297810.420438567)

Comment: Это похоже координаты в формате gps. 2-3 цифры градусы, потом минуты с долями

Answer (score 1):

Найди формулу для перевода точки в координаты. Например с gps приёмника прилетает

```
5701.0051;N;04100.1315;E
```

Что можно перевести в градусы так

```
lat = float(lat[:2]) + float(lat[2:])/60
lon = float(lon[:3]) + float(lon[3:])/60
```